# Can I run Facebook SDK in my Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making an app and integrating Facebook social login. For this to work I am using a script tag in my index.html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

However, I get this error message:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'".
```

Can I still make this work somehow?
I know I can still make the request from my server but I would want this to work from the front-end.